# Should clone(true) be used when appending cloned elements, or on() with clone(false)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When cloning an element and appending it to another element, is it better to clone the events off the original element, or using on() so the events need not be cloned?  Better is based on being faster, using less memory, and being the more official way of doing it.  Please explain why one way is better than another.  Thank you

Option 1 where events are not cloned

```
$('#add').click(function(){$("#list").append($("#clone").clone(false));};
$("#list").on("click", "a", function(){alert('hello');});
```

Option 2 where events are cloned

```
$('#add').click(function(){$("#list").append($("#clone").clone(true));};
$("#clone a").click(function(){alert('hello');});
```

HTML common to both options

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add">Click</a>
<li id="clone"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Click</a></li>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Event delegation at appropriate level works good. The reason why jQuery is using it in `on` deprecating `live` and recommentding it over `click()`

Comment: @sabithpocker: What? The non-event delegation syntax of `.on()` is equivalent to `.click()`.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you're probably not really all that concerned about performance and memory overhead.

Comment: @squint.  My main reason was my last stated reason: so I would know the official, most commonly used approach.

Comment: @user1032531: It's really just situational. Different approaches are available because different situations call for them.

Comment: @squint.  When would you recommend using clone(true)?

Comment: If we're not talking about hundreds or thousands of elements, all with the same handlers, then you could go either way. If there are many elements, you'll have overall less memory overhead by using event delegation, but more processing when an event occurs. If the event type isn't a `click`, but is instead an event that can happen repeatedly, like a `mouseover`, then I generally prefer to have the handler bound directly to the element, so there isn't that constant delegation expense taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event delegation (the `on` option); the main benefit is that you don't have to attach another event handler after appending; just define the event handling beforehand.

The main benefit is that you're not attaching a new function to each object, which means there is less memory consumed; instead, event will bubble up to the same event handling function:

```
$("#list").on("click", "a", function(){alert('hello');});

// Don't run this after appending; you're already done setting up event handling.
```

Comment: Does clone(true) create another event?

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is little slower, but eats much less memory. And it's considered the cleaner approach.